# DataTables jQuery: how to search using the value of the cells and not based from the value that is being rendered?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable that re-renders a cell to show it's value with asterisks.

It currently looks like this:
[image: table]

The json data looks like this:

```json
{
    email: "test@email.com",
    license: "license",
    expiration: "May 22, 2032"
    ... some other data
}
```

And my javascript is coded like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
    ajax: 'path/to/my/json/response.php',
    columns: [{
        data: 'email'
      },
      {
        data: 'license',
        render: (data) => tempHideKeys(data)
      },
      {
        data: 'expiration'
      },
    ],
  })
});

function tempHideKeys(string) {
  let snippet = string.match(/^.{3}/);
  let res = snippet + '*'.repeat(10);

  return res;
}
```

And I want to type in datatables' default search box the word `license` and it would display the row with the license "license". The problem is if I type in `lice` nothing shows up and I know because datatables searches the table with the values on display.

To somewhat circumvent this, I looked in the datatables' [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) on `columns.data`

Now my code on the columns looks like so:

```js
    columns: [{
        data: 'email'
      },
      {
        data: (row, type) => {
            if (type === 'filter') return row.license;
            
            return row.license;
        },
        render: (data) => tempHideKeys(data)
      },
      {
        data: 'expiration'
      },
    ],
```

...and my problem still exists.

`license` is still unsearchable and if searching `*` it returns every single row in my json data.

From my understanding, the data function of `(row, type, val, meta)` returns the data from the json and then `render` applies cosmetics to said data. Then if `type === 'filter'` (triggered when searching), it should return the untouched values before rendering.

I'm just confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `render` and return `tempHideKeys()` inside of the data function.

It should look like this:

```js
// ...
      {
        data: (row, type) => {
            if (type === 'filter') return row.license;
            
            return tempHideKeys(row.license);
        },
        // Remove this line below
        // render: (data) => tempHideKeys(data)
      },
// ...
```

---

I found the solution to my problem right after I posted my question, lol.